# Nicely format an exception into a string

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, exception

I'd like to build a nicely formatted string of a exception for logging.  Doing this from silverlight so options like nlog ([not there yet](http://nlog-project.org/forum.html#nabble-f1685105)), log4net aren't an option.

Anyone seen the code to build up something like:

```
ExceptionType: xxxx
Message: xxxx
StackTrace: XXX
InnerException
    ExceptionType: xxxx
    Message: xxxx
    StackTrace: XXX
```

I'm presently writing it myself, just hoping there's code out there to do something nicer.

**UPDATE**: I was just about to close this q as I came to the same conclusion as Zach, but not going to deprive Zach of the points! :)

The .ToString() looks like this:

```
System.Exception: I can't handle this ---> System.DivideByZeroException: Attempted to divide by zero.
   at MuckingAround.RussTest_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at MuckingAround.RussTest_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnClick()
   at System.Windows.Controls.Button.OnClick()
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Control.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(Control ctrl, EventArgs e)
   at MS.Internal.JoltHelper.FireEvent(IntPtr unmanagedObj, IntPtr unmanagedObjArgs, Int32 argsTypeIndex, String eventName)
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should get all of this by simply calling the `.ToString()` method of the exception.  We use this to log information and you get everything that I believe you are asking for.  See MSDN [`System.Exception.ToString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.tostring.aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness: the EntLib loggers let you define formatters for your application exception.

Answer (score 0):

Also, take a look at what's coming in the [Enterprise Library 5.0 Silverlight Integration Pack](http://entlib.uservoice.com), which will be addressing many of these cross-cutting concerns of LOB developers, including logging and exception handling.

Feel free to comment on the features and also please vote!